# Wicket 1.4 is being used on our legacy system, need to support MMM/dd/yyyy Datepicker date?

Tags: java, datepicker, wicket

Wicket 1.4 is being used on our legacy system, need to support MMM/dd/yyyy Datepicker date format but MMM is always converted to number e.g instead of JUL, 07 is selected from calender?

Code:

```java
final DateTextField cardHldrDOB = new DateTextField(
  PhoneChannelConstants.CARD_HLDR_DOB,
  new PropertyModel<Date> (newConAeroAcctRequestModel,PhoneChannelConstants.CARD_HLDR_DOB),
  new PatternDateConverter("MMM/dd/yyyy", true)
);

final IBehavior defaultValue = new AttributeModifier(
  PhoneChannelConstants.VALUE, true,
  new Model(PhoneChannelConstants.DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT)
);

cardHldrDOB.add(defaultValue); 

DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
datePicker.setShowOnFieldClick(true);
cardHldrDOB.add(datePicker);

cardHldrDOB.setRequired(true).add(ValidationStyleBehavior.instance());

final InputLabelBorder cardHldrDOBLbl = new InputLabelBorder(PhoneChannelConstants.CARD_HLDR_DOB,cardHldrDOB);

cardHldrDOBLbl.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true).
setOutputMarkupId(true).setVisible(true);
item.add(cardHldrDOBLbl);
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Currently your question does not give enough details. Please edit your question to include a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi martin-g, I added code to my question?